# Not show title, image and description when sharing a link on social media using react-helmet?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, seo, socialshare

I am using React helmet package in my code and i put this below code in my jsx file on react js. This method is working on change to browser tab title but the website url is share to linkedin or slack not get the page title and description. Anybody says how implement the social media share to show the title and description

```
<Helmet>
    <title>The Decision Making </title>
    <meta property="og:title" content="The Decision Making" />
    <meta name="description" content="The Decision Making is the virtual library, 
    additionally referred to as an internet library, a web library, a virtual repository" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="The Decision Making is the virtual library, 
    additionally referred to as an internet library, a web library, a virtual repository" />
</Helmet>
```